# Что такое машина состояний?

Tags: алгоритм

Объясните в упрощенном виде, пожалуйста.

Comment: А [статья](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) в вики слишком сложная?

Что именно непонятно?

Comment: зашел в вики понял только одно что это парадигма программирования а сути не понял.

Comment: @perfect, за 2 минуты **внимательно** прочли, разобрали примеры программ там, обдумали и ничего не поняли?

Здорово! Я так быстро соображать не умею.

Comment: попробую разобратся сам. спасибо

Comment: Попробуйте [другую статью][1]

  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82

Comment: не знаю правильно или нет. для себя машину состояний представил как некий черный ящик в который закладываются входящие параметры, потом  а потом этот черный ящик переходит в заданное состояние например выполняет что нибудь.

Comment: Суть не уловлена. Попробуйте еще раз

Comment: Если сравнивать с ящиком, то можно вспомнить китайскую гирлянду с коробочкой. Вы подаёте в неё сигнал кнопкой, а она меняет состояние: программу перемигивания лампочек.

Comment: Как будут перемигиваться лампочки зависит от перемигиваний в предыдущий момент времени - от предыдущего состояния автомата

Answer (score 3, accepted):

по простому, это алгоритм решения задачи, в котором для каждого элемента уже готова последовательность действий для него.
для примера, можно попробовать написать парсер имейла(Р343дло43дло23"№"№![@mail](/users/5223/mailfornothing).ru):

- если буква (состояние) - тогда переходит к след. знаку
- если цифра - к след. знаку
- если запрещенный знак - ошибка
- если @ - дальше будет доменное имя
- и тд.

такой вариант при правильном анализе даст хорошую валивацию, без него можно было бы проще решить используя шаблоны

зы я видел универсальный шаблон для имейла )

Comment: http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html Классика

Comment: с разбором строки мне стало понятно. Просто в книге по opengl говорится что opengl - это машина состояний, никак в голове уяснить не мог что бы это значило

Comment: > opengl - это машина состояний

Либо кривой перевод, либо выдрано из контекста.

Comment: @perfect - всего-то навсего имеется введу то, что у вас нет *прямой* связи между GPU и CPU.

Comment: @perfect, так Вы заинтересовались state-machine из-за фразы в книге по opengl?

Поменьше обращайте внимания на подобные "умствования". Большой ученый-теоретик видимо написал ее.